# How can I find who has sent more messages than has recieved?

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL database for a chat app and I want to find which user has sent more messages than recieved.

```
CREATE TABLE Users(uid int PRIMARY KEY, name text, phone text);

CREATE TABLE Messages( recipient int REFERENCES Users(uid),
sender int REFERENCES Users(uid), time timestamp NOT NULL, 
message text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (recipient, sender, time));
```

I've tried the one that I have in the example but it keeps showing this message

> Query Error: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'test.messages' doesn't exist"

and I can't find where I'm wrong

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fD1EvkosU3yvfmFV99MFqz/0

Comment: i think you are accessing the table from different database.
what is your database name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query, which counts the number of messages each sender has sent, and the number of messages each recipient has received in two derived tables, and then `JOIN`s those table to the `Users` table based on the `uid` matching the sender or the recipient. It then selects only users who have sent more messages than they have received:

```
SELECT u.name, m1.sent, m2.received
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sender, COUNT(*) AS sent
           FROM Messages 
           GROUP BY sender) m1 ON m1.sender = u.uid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT recipient, COUNT(*) AS received
           FROM Messages 
           GROUP BY recipient) m2 ON m2.recipient = u.uid
WHERE sent > received
```

Output:

```
name    sent    received
John    4       3
Jim     5       2
Luis    3       1
```

[Updated demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fD1EvkosU3yvfmFV99MFqz/1)